# NodeJS still "work" even if it can't perfom any query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm developing an application which try to perform some interactions with MySQL.
The strange behaviour is that at one point insert or update commands are no longer performed, but the application does not throw exceptions.
I'm using `createPool` to manage many connections at a time and I didn't change its default `connectionLimit` (I'll increase it as soon as possible).
Is possible that this default value represents the cause of my issue? What happens if I exceed the connectionLimit?

Any comment on code quality is accepted!

Constructor:

```
function MySQLHandler(connectionParams, logger) {
  if(!connectionParams) {
    throw new Error("connectionParams is null");
  }
  if(!connectionParams.host || !connectionParams.user || !connectionParams.password || !connectionParams.database) {
    throw new Error("connectionParams not properly setted");
  }
  this.connectionParams = connectionParams;
  this.mysqlConn = mysql.createPool({
        host: this.connectionParams.host,
        user: this.connectionParams.user,
        password: this.connectionParams.password,
        database: this.connectionParams.database
    });
  this.logger = logger;
}
```

All the functions call this:

```
MySQLHandler.prototype.query = function (queryString, params, callback) {
  this.logger.log(queryString);

  let _logger = this.logger;
  this.mysqlConn.getConnection(
    function(err, connection) {
      if(err) {
        _logger.error(err);
        return callback(err, null);
      }
      connection.query(queryString, params, function(err, success) {
        connection.release();

        if(err) {
          _logger.error(err);
          return callback(err, null);
        }
        return callback(null, success);
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your problem that *1)* nodejs doesn't throw exceptions or that *2)* the statements aren't executed?

Comment: Post your code, its impossible to debug code accurately without any code...

Comment: You probably have an unlogged error somewhere - perhaps leaking a db connection and then you run out.  We can't possibly help you without seeing your code.

Comment: @Al.G. if a statements fails, I like to see an exception.

Comment: @peteb you are right, but the project is big and I don't know which portion is useful and which no. Please, tell me if you need other.

Comment: Does *_logger.error(err);* count as 'an exception'? I.e. do you want to `throw Error()`s or do you want to understand why your query fails?

Comment: @Al.G. I want to understand why my query has success (for example) for 3 hours and then, the same never be executed and no error log is written. I have to restart the application to work correctly.